# Android 13 read media image permission not working

Tags: java, android-permissions, android-external-storage, android-storage, android-13

I am trying to store image bitmap to External Storage.

As per documentation we need only read media image permission but in real device it shows permission required to write into storage.

I can read gallery images but not able to write to external storage.